# ErrorException Undefined property stdClass::$Start

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I ran into an error while fetching data from my `goals` table. I'm trying to display all the tables data using `foreach` loop. But I can't due to unknown property error. I'm still learning laravel so kindly help.
Here's my controller code.

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;


use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\goal;
use DB;

class GoalController extends Controller
{
    public function postAddGoal(Request $request){
        $this->validate($request, [
            'goal'=>'required',
            'checklist'=>'required'
        ]);
        $goal_name=$request['goal'];
        $checklist=$request['checklist'];

        $goal = new goal();
        $goal->goal=$goal_name;
        $goal->checklist=$checklist;
        $goal->status='PENDING';
        $goal->start='1002-1-1';
        $goal->finish='1002-1-1';
        $goal->remarks="NULL";
        $goal->score="0";
        $goal->save();

        redirect()->route('seegoals');
    }

    public function getGoals(){
        $goals = DB::select(' select * from goals ');
        if(empty($goals)){
            $goals=0;
        }
        return view('/index', ['goals'=>$goals] );
    }
}
```

Then my index.blade.php code

```
@foreach($goals as $goal)
<tr>

    <th colspan="3">{{ $goal->goal }}</th>
    <th colspan="7">{{$goal->checklist}}</th>
    <th colspan="2">{{$goal->status}}</th>
    <th colspan="2">{{$goal->Start}}</th>
    <th colspan="2">{{$goal->finish}}</th>
    <th colspan="2">{{$goal->score}}</th>
    <th colspan="7">{{$goal->remarks}}</th>

</tr>
@endforeach
```

I get an exception:

> (2/2) ErrorException Undefined property: stdClass::$Start (View:
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/ToDo/resources/views/index.blade.php)

What could be the problem with my code?

Answer (score 2):

There is misleading of first letter. Change `Start` to `start`

```
<th colspan="2">{{$goal->start}}</th>
```

And for good practice in controller change code to

```
$goals = DB::select('select `checklist`, `status`, `start`, `finish`, `score`, `remarks` from goals');
```

You must be get in db only needed info

 also delete this part

```
if (empty($goals)) {
    $goals = 0;
}
```

For not get error when goals is empty

Comment: Try it and ask result.

Comment: @Erickioko Remember, when using the query builder is not the same using Eloquent, With Eloquent that `$goal->Start` will show you null (empty string), because of the dinamyc properties. So `$goals = DB::select(' select * from goals ');` can be done with Eloquent Like `$goals = goal::all();`

Comment: @Erickioko I update my answer see also good practice and second bug fix